# Getting Inner Text of dragged Element in Angular Material DragAndDrop

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-cdk-drag-drop

Is there any way to get the innerText of the dragged element and use it in "onDrop" function on angular cdkDragAndDrop ?

```
onDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {

   if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
  
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);

   } 
   else {
      console.log(DraggedElementInnerText)
      this.addItemInPostion(event.currentIndex,DraggedElementInnerText)
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved :

this how to get the dragged element: event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex]